# Installing Nuget Packages globally

Tags: c#, nuget, package-management

Is there a way to install Nuget Packages globally?

I have a Nuget Package that I would like to use across multiple projects without having to download for each project?

Each project will have its own solution and it will be independent of other project.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this question. [This blog post](http://blog.nuget.org/20141010/nuget-is-broken.html) by the NuGet dev lead from october 2014 lists "Global Package Installation" as one of the open issues.  Don't know if it's fixed by now though.

Comment: I wish there were a way. I experiment a lot and create new solutions every day and have had to re-download everything every time so far. Even in case there is no official way there is to be a tool capable of copying NuGet packages from one solution into another and/or maintaining a cache of them.

Comment: If the package is a tool, use `dotnet tool install -g <package>`. For more information, see https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/05/12/dotnet-global-tools/.

Answer (score 6):

NuGet in its current version uses a global package cache.

Have a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache) to find out where it is on your machine. You should also poke around the NuGet configuration file documentation for how to update the global cache location.